# Replicate sumif formula across a row in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is there a way to replicate the formula below in excel onto a Power BI measure?

I want for each company to return the total number of countries it applied for.

Many thanks in advance
Nasos

[image]

Comment: Is this what your data table looks like or what your visual looks like?

Comment: My data table looks like columns A to E and is called "Countries", In excel I used column F for the formula calculation.

Comment: Unpivoting columns B:E would make this much easier. Are you able to do that?

Comment: I will try this and let you know tomorrow. Would unpivoting work if there were more countries added?

Comment: You will need to use unpivot other columns, this will work for more countries being added. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Unpivoting-Variable-Number-of-Columns/td-p/1381097 Once unpivoted, the measure is a simple countrows where country = "y".